# JEE6 Global JNDI Name and Maven Deployment

Tags: maven-2, ejb-3.0, jndi

I'm having some problems with the global JNDI names of my EJB resources which is (or at least will) cause my JNDI look ups to fail. The project is being developed on Netbeans and is a standard Maven Web Application. When my application is deployed to GF3.0 the application name is set to something like:

com.example_myapp_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT

which is all well and good from Netbeans point of view because it ensures the name is unique but it also means all the EJBs get global names such as this:

java:global/com.example_myapp_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT/CustomerService

This, of course, is going to cause problems because every time the version changes all the global names change (I've tested this by changing the version and the names indeed changed). The name is being generated from the POM file and it's a concatenation of:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Up until now I've got away with just injecting all the resources using @EJB but now I need to access the CustomerService EJB from a JSF Converter so I'm doing a JNDI look up like this:

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    CustomerService customerService = (CustomerService)ctx.lookup( "java:global/com.example_myapp_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT/CustomerService" );
    return customerService.get(submittedValue);
} catch( Exception e ) {
    logger.error( "Failed to convert customer.", e );
    return null;
}
```

which will clearly break when the application is properly released and the module name changes. So, the million dollar question: how can I set the modle name in maven or how do I recover the [module name](http://blogs.oracle.com/MaheshKannan/entry/portable_global_jndi_names) so that I can programatically build the JNDI name at runtile. I've tried setting it in the web.xml file as suggested by that link but it was ignored. I think I'd rather build the name at runtime as that means there is less scope for screw ups when the application is deployed.

Many thanks for any help, I've been tearing my hair out all day on this.

Comment: How are you doing deployment? cargo? Do you use war-plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the EJB is included in the WAR, just use the java:module alias:

```
java:module/CustomerService
```

Comment: That got it, many thanks. To anyone else having this problem some additional information can be found here: http://blogs.oracle.com/kensaks/entry/application_specified_portable_jndi_names

Comment: This works perfectly UNTIL you try to do it out of a Quartz job. I assume it's because Quartz runs it's own Threads outside the container context etc (btw, yes, I DID manage to manually construct a working InitialContext). ONLY the global JNDI lookup worked. Which means I'm stuck with setting the final build name in maven. But that is NOT a guarantee, since a deployer CAN change the name of the deployed app. Any one got something better (to make it all work from within a Quartz job?)

Comment: @demaniak Is it possible to capture `java:app/AppName` and `java:module/ModuleName` on an EE thread and pass it to the Quartz job, which can recompose a `java:global/<app>/<module>/<bean>` name?

Comment: Hi bkail - it is possible to feed the job arbitrary data (like AppName and ModuleName) through it's JobDataMap. The question is - where do you programmatically retrieve the AppName to start with? Just to be clear: the java:module/ModuleName alias does not work when calling from a Quartz job (hardcoded). I briefly tried the java:app/AppName also - no luck. For now the hardcoded global JNDI name is working - less than ideal, but I'll take it.Side note: I also passed a reference to the bean via the JobDataMap, but that failed due to JPA transaction issues.

Comment: @demaniak You have to retrieve AppName/ModuleName from an EE thread and pass it through (via JobDataMap, or so? I've never used Quartz). If that doesn't make sense, it's probably easiest to start a new question with specific code snippets showing the creation and execution of the Quartz job.

Comment: Thank you bkail, I will take that under advisement. Will probably start a new question once the current project is out the door, and I have some breathing room.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I set the modle name in maven or how do I recover the module name so that I can programatically build the JNDI name at runtime.

Well, as written in the provided link, about the `module-name` of *Portable Global JNDI name in EJB 3.1*:

> **`<module-name>`**  defaults to bundle name (.war or .jar) without the bundle extension.

So I would configure Maven and set the `finalName` to not include the version in the name of the WAR:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

Not sure why NetBeans includes the package name and underscore (NetBeans is doing that, right?) when deploying on GlassFish and if you can avoid NB doing that.

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried that <finalName>myapp</finalName> and it didn't help. It did, however, stop the version being included in the name of the war.

To be honest I'm not sure if it's maven or netbeans that is deploying the application with the name "com.example_myapp_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT" but that is the name shown in the GF admin console. I know the parts of the name come from the POM so I assume it's Maven that's generating the name. I think GF is running the application from the target war directory so not picking up the name of the war file.